# Target Specific mobile devices from a browser?

Tags: blackberry, mobile

Could anyone please offer some advice on how to target Blackberry differently to other devices from within a browser?  Is there such a thing as a detection script via Jquery or Javascipt?  Or is there a better solution?

Any advice gratefully received!

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little tricky, not all the phone OS's are distinguishable from a user_agent string (though iPad/iPhone should be iirc)

In addition, not all mobile browsers can even handle Javascript in the first place.

There is a school of thought that given JS-support in modern desktop browsers you can assume any non-javascript browser to be a mobile device.

Notable exception...iPhone does handle JS, but as mentioned above you can find that one with a regular browserdetection through the UA string.

Also worth looking at the CSS command

```
@media handheld
```

This lets you write 2 CSS's, one for screens, the other for portables.  Drawback here is that a lot of mobiles devices either dont support CSS at all, or act/load like a regular screen anyway.

Try this link for a further discussion, theres a nice PHP useragent parser example, you could probably pickup blackberry if you can find its tag somewhere.  WURFL is also mentioned and is probably the most adaptable solution

http://webdesign.about.com/od/mobile/a/detect-mobile-devices.htm